# Can acetone be used as a GC–MS solvent for a sample containing ammonia?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography, mass-spectrometry

Сan acetone be used as a GC–MS solvent/diluent for a sample containing ammonia? Will there be a reaction between these two species?

Comment: It could form the corresponding imine, specially at high temperature in GC/MS.